# Multiple Document upload with multiple metadata set

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to customize the document library upload form in such a way that if user has uploaded 2 files. The next metadata form should show 2 sets of metadata form like if I have 2 properties I should see 2 set of 2 properties.I can then set all properties for both files and save and redirect to some different page.

I created custom rendering template for document lib new form. I am stuck here now..

Is it possible to know how many files user has uploaded in previous form and then render properties multiple times using documentlibfields class in metadata form?

Any pointers /suggestions would be useful...

Comment: I had to disable multiple file upload as users were not filling out the metadata. When we had multiple file upload turned on, the uploaded files had checked out the user until he/she filled out the metadata for each document. I tried to do what you want to do but trust me you are inviting troubles.

Comment: I honestly think that this would be something that you would have to write all in code. I have toyed with using a grid view that handles this, but it really is complex. For 2 or 3 files it is not worth the effort. It may depend on how often and how many files will be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite hard to accomplish something like that. You would need to write custom code for it, and for some reason I get the feeling that those documents are tied to each other in some way.

Is it an idea to use document sets, as I get the feeling that those documents are in some way tied together to each other. You can add a (declarative) workflow to handle file uploads for that document set and use that workflow to set metadata on both documents, whenever all documents are in.

edit: sorry, just saw it was sharepoint-foundation. It doesn't support document sets :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the Upload form to track the uploaded documents
   and get the id of those document Items.
Based on that Item Id's, you
   can redirect to customized edit Form page, to edit multiple Form
   Properties (that contains Edit Form Controls).
Instead of
   redirection, you can show the multiple form controls to edit the
   documents in the same Page.